# Randomly Generating Patterns Using Hexagonal Images

Tags: android, algorithm, random, hexagonal-tiles

Okay so I have these images:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Basically what I'm trying to do is to create a "mosaic" of about 5 to 12 hexagons, with most of them roughly centralised, and where all of the lines meet up.

For example:

[image]
[image]
[image]

I'm aware that I could probably just brute-force it, but as I'm developing for Android I need a faster, more efficient and less processor-intensive way of doing it.

Can anybody provide me with a solution, or even just point me in the right direction?

Comment: no hex can have 5 or 6 neighbors ?

Comment: Nope, just using the images I linked to

Comment: Actually on second thoughts, they can have 5 or 6 neighbours, but they just can't be be "connected" to them (via the internal lines in the hexagons)

Comment: in this case, I think the connection part is secondary to this matter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A random idea that I had is to go with what Deepak said about defining a class that tracks the state of each of its six edges (say, in an `int[] neighbor` in which neighbor[0] states if top edge has neighbor, neighbor[1] states if top-right edge has neighbor, and so on going clockwise)

Then for each hexagon on screen, convert its array to an integer via binary. Based on that integer, use a lookup table to determine which hexagon image to use + how it should be oriented/flipped, then assign that hexagon object to that image.

For instance, let's take the central hexagon with four neighbors in your first screenshot. Its array would be `[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]` based on the scheme mentioned above. Take neighbor[0] to be the least-significant bit (2^0) and neighbor[5] to be the most-significant bit (2^5), and we have `[1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1] --> 45`. Somewhere in a lookup table we would have already defined 45 to mean *the 5th hexagon image, flipped horizontally**, among the seven base hexagon icons you've posted.

Yes, brute-force is involved, but it's a "smarter" brute-force since you're not rotating to see if a hexagon will fit. Rather, it involves a more efficient look-up table.

*or rotated 120 degrees clockwise if you prefer ;)

Comment: Changed this to my accepted answer as it gives a lot more detail. I'll have a go of this and see how I get on, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Nice and tricky question. What you can start with is define object for each image which has attributes that specify which edge has a line attached to it.                               Then while adding the images in the layout you can rotate it in such a way that the edge with line in one image lies adjacent to the other image's edge with line. It may be little complicated but I hope you can at least start with something like this.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking of starting with this
However, other problems I'm facing are things like fitting it all on a phone screen (so the whole thing can't be more than about 4 hexagons across), and also getting the algorithm to terminate (i.e. making all the lines completely join up)

Comment: welcome :) please do remember to upvote the answer or accept the answer if you find it to be useful in anyway :)